# codeigniter [upload file] $this->input->post('namefile') not working

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

i pass file view to controller

view `<input type="file" name="ssss" >`

conreoller

if me use `$_FILES['ssss']`  is working

but

im use `$this->input->post('ssss')` is null

why call post is null ?

Comment: Because it is a file not a post http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

This code will upload your file.

```
$file=$_FILES['ssss']['name'];                      
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ssss']['tmp_name'],'upload/'.$file);
                  $data['file']=$img;
```

it is not in post because it is `$_FILES` not `$_POST` thats why cant be uploaded using post format.

Good Luck!